# iPad and email link - how do close the full screen mail app?

Tags: ipad, email, browser

I am testing a website on an Ipad. It seems that if someone clicks on an email link, an email program will open in full screen (taking the user away from the browser). What makes it annoying is, there is no "close or X" button for them to leave the mail program. How do my ipad Visitors go back to the browser?

Is there a way (or a HTML code) where if someone click on an email link on an Ipad, it will open up the email program in a small window without taking the visitors away from the brower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS's UI is based on the concept of full-screen apps. To return to the browser, your user must return to the browser *app*. This can be done using the button, or (if configured) some multi-touch gestures (I use a 4-finger swipe to the side, but I can't remember what the default is).

You should not be trying to change the user interface of a specific device from your website. You might help a few users who have not yet got used to their iOS interface, but you will confuse and/or annoy all the ones who have.

If I wrote to you and asked for help because everyone else in the whole continent was driving on the wrong side of the road, would you try to fix the entire road system? No! I hope you'd just tell me how (or not) to drive. Same deal with the existing UI on any device — let your user learn to use it properly.